# Check when computer was turned on for Windows

Tags: windows, uptime

On a Windows computer, is there a way to see the date and time when the computer was booted/turned on/powered on? Something like the Linux uptime command.

But I'd rather it display the exact time when it was turned on, not the time that has passed since then. For example if you turned it on today at 14:30, it would display something like `9/16/2016 14:30`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606774/how-to-get-the-uptime-in-windows). This is a fairly long article about the different methods.

Summary:

Interesting for you:

- systeminfo (shows absolute time)

  > systeminfo | findstr "System Boot Time:"
- net statistics (shows absolute time)

  > net statistics workstation

  or

  > net statistics server

  depending on your computer's role
- Powershell

  > Get-WinEvent -ProviderName eventlog | Where-Object {$*.Id -eq 6005 -or $*.Id -eq 6006}
- WMI

  > wmic os get lastbootuptime

Not interesting for you:

- Task Manager (shows the passed-since-then time)
- Uptime utility (requires separate tool, shows passed-since-then time)

Credits go to [the author of the quoted community wiki article](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1237296).

Comment: systeminfo | findstr "System Boot Time:" gives me the time of last shutdown only...